# Xcode 7 Json Fetching always crashing

Tags: nsjsonserialization, xcode7

Whenever I am trying to fetch data through JSon in xcode 7 it is giving me error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

In xcode 6 it is working fine. Is new method has been implemented in xcode 7 to fetch data from json .

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139"]];


id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error:&error];
if (!data)
{
    NSLog(@"Download Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}

// Parsing the JSON data received from web service into an NSDictionary object
NSDictionary *jSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];
```

try this its working

Comment: NSlog("%@",jSON) ur data is displaying

Comment: On xcode 6 it is working and also my old code is working on xcode 6 but not on xcode 7 . Error is :
    Could not connect to server 
Always with every URL.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 9.0 it will no more support http:// it need https://

adding this to info.plist solve the issue but don't know will apple allow such app to publish in app store .

```
< key>NSAppTransportSecurity< / key>
     < dict>
        < key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads< / key>< true/>
     < / dict>
```

Adding this by editing info.plist in text editor doesn't work , has to do from xcode itself. (I am a new to programming)

Comment: Yep, this worked for me (Only the plist key cause I dont have a SSL in my server) Thanks.